# Is there a mathematical notation to write that, in a multiset of elements S, at least two of those elements are different?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

I'm looking to write down formally that a multiset of elements contains at least two elements that differs in value.
e.g.,
S1 = {1,1,1,1,1,1} and S2={1,1,1,1,0,1}
S1 has all identical elements, S2 has at least two elements that differs in value.

Comment: what you named $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not sets, a set cannot have repeated elements. $S_1$ and $S_2$ are multisets. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)

Comment: Depending on how the OP is using these objects, they may be better described as tuples or sequences instead if the order in which the elements are presented matters.  As a multiset, $\{1,1,1,1,0,1\}$ is considered equal to $\{1,1,1,1,1,0\}$ whereas as tuples $(1,1,1,1,0,1)$ is considered different than $(1,1,1,1,1,0)$.  Now... if you really *are* talking about sets, then note that $\{1,1,1,1,1,1\}=\{1\}$ since any redundant elements can be removed from the representation.  You would have then the cardinality of $S_1$ is $1$ while the cardinality of $S_2=\{1,0\}$ is $2$

Comment: ok, thanks it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $\exists x \exists y (x\in S \wedge y \in S \wedge x \neq y)$.  This works whether $S$ is a set, multiset, or tuple as discussed in the comments to your question.

Comment: Thank you Ross, that's the kind of notation I was wondering. Very elegant, compact and understandable! Very happy with all your answer, I learn a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest

> $S$ contains at least two elements that differs in value.

Don't mistake the lack of formulas for a lack of mathematical formality.

Comment: you right and I agree. In fact, I also try to learn how to formally write and read such proposal in formal mathematics notations.